# Generate output using loops?

Tags: java

Expected result:

> ```
> (1 - 250)
> START = 870136
> END   = 870385
>
> (251 - 500)
> START = 870386
> END   = 870635
>
> (501 - 750)
> START = 870636
> END   = 870885
>
> (751 - 1000)
> START = 870886
> END   = 871135
>
> (1001 - 1250)
> START = 871136
> END   = 871385
>
> (1251 - 1500)
> START = 871386
> END   = 871635
>
> (1501 - 1750)
> START = 871636
> END   = 871885
>
> (1751 - 2000)
> START = 871886
> END   = 872135
> ```

My attempt:

```
package Calculator;

public class Calculation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int number1 = 1000;
        int number2 = 2000;
        int number3 = 250;
        System.out.println("======================");

        for(int i = 0; i < number2; i+=number3) {
              number1++;
              System.out.println("Start = " + (number1 - 1));
              System.out.println("End   = " + (number1 - 1 + number3));
              System.out.println("Start = " + (number1 + number3));
        }System.out.println("======================");

        for (int i = 0; i <= number2; i+=number3) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }System.out.println("======================");

        for (int i1 = 1; i1 <= number2; i1+=number3) {
            System.out.println(i1);
        }System.out.println("======================");
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably you need to use loops. If you already tried [edit] your question and include your best attempt(s). Describe *specific* problem which you are facing.

Comment: You provided your code, that is good. Not try to explain problem you are facing with it. What you expected to get and what happened instead?

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Pshemo.. Can OP please explain the logic he's trying to achieve. That's really help in solving the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer following code snippet

```
public class Calculation {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int start = 870136 - 250;
        int end = 870385 - 250;

        for(int i=1; i<=2000; i=i+250) {
            start = start + 250;
            end = end + 250;

            System.out.println("(" + i + "-" + (i+250 - 1) + ")");
            System.out.println("START = " + start);
            System.out.println("END = " + end + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. By the way my main target is ( "Value1" loop by "Value2" then Divide into "Value3") and print out same as output attached?

Comment: Thank you soo much Nitin, I figure it out and the system is done. ^_^

Comment: Do accept the answer if it satisfys your question and fixed your problem.

Answer (score 2):

extract the common stuffs that you want to print into a separate method.

```
void print(int index){

     int from = index * 250 + 1;
     int to = (index+1) *250;
     int start = BASE +from;
     int end = BASE + to;
     System.out.printf("(%d - %d) START %d END %d", from, to, start, end);

}
```

where BASE is your static int value

```
static int BASE =879_886;
```

you can do a loop with something like the following

```
for (int i = 0; i<8; i++){
    print(i);
}
```

Comment: hope it helps :D

Comment: Hi, Thank for your help.